# hidden files with .icloud extension in ubiquity container

Tags: ios, icloud

I am building app which syncs documents over the iCloud.

When I create document (lets say its name is myfile1.doc) in one device and expect to appear in another one I get nothing - it looks like it doesn't sync. To my surprise when I read the content of `Documents` folder in ubiquity container I can see the representation of the file is added as a hidden file with .icloud extension (in this case .myfile1.doc.icloud).

I tried to find more about this .icloud files but so far no results.
Anyone know what are they representing? Is it the metadata item that indicates that file was added to iCloud and I should manually download it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think hidden files are handled by metadataQuery to indicate that the new file was added to iCloud and is waiting to be sync'ed. NSMetadataQuery recognizes them as representation of new files not yet downloaded to ubiquity container.

Comment: Have you found out a way to trigger these files to sync/download?

Comment: Okay, found it. `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:` of `NSFileManager`. :)

Answer (score 1):

These files are not documented and you should ignore them. If you want to know what's in them, open one in a hex editor and have a look. Your code should not check for them or access them in any way.